# Android Curl Rest

Tags: android, curl

I've developed an android app and an external server node js link with a mongodb db . How I manage to link them ? I need to call a CURL function for example during the building of the app

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '
  {
"email":"l.andrea195@live.it",
"PreferedBook":[["Harry Potter e la pietra filosofale","J.K.Rowling","26/06/1997"]],
"BooksRead": ["La pietra filosofale"],
"notes":[],
"genre": ["Thriller", "Fantasy"],
"numberorReviews":0
```

}
' http://localhost:4002/readers

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the issue through the Retrofit library! In particular I follow that link https://square.github.io/retrofit/ that let me to see how we can interact with my server that makes requests to the non relational database mongodb